# Calling methods from .ashx handler from aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, ashx

I'm having a bit of trouble calling a method from a generic handler we have. I've tried using two separate techniques to call a simple 'HelloWorld()' method but I get two different errors:

The first technique is as follows:

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["method"] = "HelloWorld";


        byte[] data;

        try
        {
            data = wc.UploadValues(_domain, formData);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            return;
        }

        string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        Label1.Text = response;

        wc.Dispose();
```

and I get the following error:

```
{"id":null,"error":{"name":"Found String where Object was expected."}}
```

and the second technique I've tried is:

```
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_domain);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"method\":\"helloWorld\"}"; //," +
            //"\"password\":\"bla\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            try
            {
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                Label2.Text = wex.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label2.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

and with this, I get the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

When I test the call from the ".ashx?test" page the method runs and the details at the bottom of the screen are:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2013 13:46:19 GMT
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 32
Expires: -1
```

Any ideas as to why this wouldn't be working?

Thanks!

Comment: There should never be a need to call an ashx handler from an aspx page. Refactor your code so that the logic inside the ashx handler is moved to a reusable class.

Comment: @BradM maybe it's on a different server...

Comment: @BradM Unfortunately this is the way we need to do it in this case.

Comment: @Mr47 Possibly, but he states that it's a handler "we" have.

Answer (score 4):

An ASHX handler is not a web service. You don't call methods within the ASXH handler. You just call the handler, and it delivers data directly, be it a text or binary data - that's up to you.

Comment: What would be the best method to call the handler? Bearing in mind I can't refactor anything.

Comment: What do you see when you call the ASHX in a browser? What is HelloWorld supposed to return?

Comment: It's returning json and this particular method is just returning a string.

Comment: Well, you can only work with what the handler returns. Make a WebRequest, and use the Response content. Should be pure text.